# Java SQL INSERT INTO use of eclipse function not working with Myconnection.getconnection();

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm trying to let my button push (INSERT INTO) Username & Password to my database with the use of eclipse program. Netbeans provides the Myconnection.getConnection(); but in eclipse it give me an error. I tried a different way to code it with Connection conn = Drivermanager.getConnection();

But when I use this I need to put Class.forname("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"). When using this my catch has to be (Exception e).
But for my sql I NEED catch (SQLException e). But then again my Class.forname gives me an error. Anyone who knows how to fix this issue?

```
package Registeren;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;

import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;

public class Registeren {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField txtRegUsername;
    private JPasswordField txtRegPassword;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Registeren window = new Registeren();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Registeren() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 1376, 869);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        panel.setBorder(null);

        JLabel lblRegistreren = new JLabel("REGISTREREN");
        lblRegistreren.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(82, 16));
        lblRegistreren.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 80));

        JLabel lblUsername = new JLabel("Gebruikersnaam");
        lblUsername.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));

        txtRegUsername = new JTextField();
        txtRegUsername.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        txtRegUsername.setColumns(10);
        txtRegUsername.setAutoscrolls(false);

        JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Wachtwoord");
        lblPassword.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));

        JButton btnRegister = new JButton("Aanmaken");
        btnRegister.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    String driver = "com.mysql.jbdc.Driver";
                    Class.forName(driver);
                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/restaurant", "root", "");

                    String User = txtRegUsername.getText();
                    String Pass = String.copyValueOf(txtRegPassword.getPassword());

                    String sql = " insert into login (Username, Password)" + " values (?, ?)";

                      PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

                      stmt.setString (1, User);
                      stmt.setString (2, Pass);


                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nieuwe gebruikers toegevoegd!");
                      stmt.execute();

                      con.close();


                } catch(Exception ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Registeren.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

                }

            }
        });


        btnRegister.setBorder(null);
        btnRegister.setBackground(new Color(46, 139, 87));
        btnRegister.setAutoscrolls(true);

        JButton btnDeleteUser = new JButton("Verwijderen");
        btnDeleteUser.setBorder(null);
        btnDeleteUser.setBackground(new Color(255, 0, 0));
        btnDeleteUser.setAutoscrolls(true);

        txtRegPassword = new JPasswordField();
        GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(frame.getContentPane());
        groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(panel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 364, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(201)
                            .addComponent(lblRegistreren, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(224)
                            .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(btnRegister, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 136, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(btnDeleteUser, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 136, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addComponent(lblPassword, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 236, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addComponent(lblUsername, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 217, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addComponent(txtRegPassword, 304, 304, 304)
                                        .addComponent(txtRegUsername, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 304, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))))
                    .addGap(211))
        );
        groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(panel, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 822, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(41)
                    .addComponent(lblRegistreren, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 155, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 228, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(6)
                            .addComponent(lblUsername, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addComponent(txtRegUsername, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 43, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(37)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(lblPassword, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 43, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(90))
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(txtRegPassword, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(81)))
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(btnRegister, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 49, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(btnDeleteUser, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 49, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(136))
        );
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(groupLayout);
    }
}
```

The error show up after

```
try { 
    String driver = "com.mysql.jbdc.Driver";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/restaurant","root","");
 ***Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");*** <-- ERROR
```

[SQLException into Exception ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0ccQ.png)

[ERROR Class.forname](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vaiij.png)

[Username and Password INSERT INTO mysql database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzZAX.png)

---

So I have made a new project java. Added everything new again. It looks like the Class.forname(Driver); isn't connecting the right way.

```
    package Registeren;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Register {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField txtRegUsername;
    private JPasswordField txtRegPassword;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Register window = new Register();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Register() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 1442, 938);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(null);
        panel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

        JLabel lblRegisteren = new JLabel("REGISTREREN");
        lblRegisteren.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(82, 16));
        lblRegisteren.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 80));

        JLabel lblUsername = new JLabel("Gebruikersnaam");
        lblUsername.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));

        txtRegUsername = new JTextField();
        txtRegUsername.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        txtRegUsername.setColumns(10);
        txtRegUsername.setAutoscrolls(false);

        JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Wachtwoord");
        lblPassword.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));

        txtRegPassword = new JPasswordField();

        JButton btnRegister = new JButton("Aanmaken");
        btnRegister.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    String driver = "com.mysql.jbdc.Driver";
                    Class.forName(driver);
                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/restaurant", "root", "");

                    String User = txtRegUsername.getText();
                    String Pass = String.copyValueOf(txtRegPassword.getPassword());

                    String sql = " insert into login (Username, Password)" + " values (?, ?)";

                      PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

                      stmt.setString (1, User);
                      stmt.setString (2, Pass);


                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nieuwe gebruikers toegevoegd!");
                      stmt.execute();

                      con.close();


                } catch(Exception ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Register.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

                }

            }
        });
        btnRegister.setBorder(null);
        btnRegister.setBackground(new Color(46, 139, 87));
        btnRegister.setAutoscrolls(true);

        JButton btnDelete = new JButton("Verwijderen");
        btnDelete.setBorder(null);
        btnDelete.setBackground(Color.RED);
        btnDelete.setAutoscrolls(true);
        GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(frame.getContentPane());
        groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(panel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 364, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(201)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(lblRegisteren, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 582, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(23)
                            .addComponent(lblUsername, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 217, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(24)
                            .addComponent(txtRegUsername, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 304, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(23)
                            .addComponent(lblPassword, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 236, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(5)
                            .addComponent(txtRegPassword, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 304, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(23)
                            .addComponent(btnRegister, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 136, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(273)
                            .addComponent(btnDelete, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 136, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addContainerGap(277, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(lblRegisteren, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 155, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(228)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(6)
                            .addComponent(lblUsername, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addComponent(txtRegUsername, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 43, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(37)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(lblPassword, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 43, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(8)
                            .addComponent(txtRegPassword, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGap(81)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(btnRegister, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 49, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(btnDelete, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 49, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addComponent(panel, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 891, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(groupLayout);
    }
}
```

**The following shows up to error**

> Mar 23, 2019 6:46:38 PM Registeren.Register$2 actionPerformed SEVERE:
>   null ***java.lang.ClassNotFoundException***: com.mysql.jbdc.Driver    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(N***ative Method***)     at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)   at
>   Registeren.Register$2.actionPerformed(***Register.java:88***)     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

ERROR: Class.forname(driver);

```
    try {
        String driver = "com.mysql.jbdc.Driver";
        Class.forName(driver);
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/restaurant", "root", "");
```

Comment: No never use a password atm because it isn't publiced yet

Comment: You want to catch SQLExceptions and Exceptions separately?

Comment: No not really what I ment. I'm trying to get my Username & password into my database but It pops up an error.

Comment: Where is your txtRegPassword text field and you should have SQLExceptions and Exception there? And, make sure you have added MySQL Connector/J .

Comment: @Harshana txtRegPassword is there and Exception is there to. I have added the MySQL Connector/J aswell. My SELECT sql works fine. I tried it and it logs me in to the program. But to make a new user doesn't work.

Comment: Updated program is working, If you have installed connectorJ so then you have to set the class path to that jar file location. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-installing-classpath.html

Answer (score 0):

As of Java 6, you haven't ***needed*** `Class.forName`; but it doesn't hurt anything to add it (correctly). You would resolve the class **before** attempting to get it with `DriverManager` (and `SQLException` is a sub-class of `Exception`, catching just `Exception` is fine). Like,

```
btnRegister.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        try {
            String driver = "com.mysql.jbdc.Driver";
            Class.forName(driver);
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/restaurant", "root", "");

            String User = txtRegUsername.getText();
            String Pass = String.copyValueOf(txtRegPassword.getPassword());

            String sql = " insert into login (Username, Password)" + " values (?, ?)";

            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

            stmt.setString(1, User);
            stmt.setString(2, Pass);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nieuwe gebruikers toegevoegd!");
            stmt.execute();

            con.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Registeren.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        }

    }
});
```

Comment: A different error pops up I have added it into an image above

Comment: You didn't change `SQLException` to `Exception`.

Comment: Yes I don't haven't I? In the first picture there you can see I have changed SQLException to Exception

Comment: I have compiled the snippet above; and I cannot reproduce. Restart your ide. Try a clean build. Test it with another compiler. Actually edit your question to include relevant details, don't keep adding images (unless it actually shows something that can't be captured by plain text).

Comment: check my new post. I have added everything

Comment: You didn't edit your question, you posted an answer; regardless, the error you are seeing means you haven't correctly added the jar file from [mysql connector/j](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/). Which IDE are you using?

Comment: The issue was String driver = "com.mysql.jbdc.Driver"; it should have been jdbc.Driver instead of jbdc.Driver! Thank you anyway!